# using $_GET with PHP if statement and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, get

So I'm having a problem with the logic behind this statement on my PHP login website. Here is the code:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$results=mysql_query("SELECT temporary_password FROM $tbl_name");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

if($_GET['temp_password'] != $row['temporary_password'] && $_GET['temp_username'] != $row['temporary_username']){
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

basically I have a registration webpage that should only be accessed if the users URL contains both temp_username AND temp_password and that both of those variables exist inside the database. Currently I can get this to work using OR (||) instead of AND (&&) this statement only works if either password OR username exists, but I want the person to access this site only if both temp_username and temp_password are true, otherwise forward to the index page.

what's wrong with my logic?

P.S. I know mysql_* is not secure, I currently don't have time to transition to mysqli.

Comment: *"I currently don't have time to transition to mysqli."* You'll regret this.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: you don't have the time to put an `i` into your function calls? mysqli is pretty much a drop-in replacement for mysql... Plus, you're not fetching temp_username from your table, so that part of the if() will ALWAYS fail.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: @AwladLiton is correct. Using `&&` will mean that people can get through if either the username or password matches. Using `||` is correct.

Comment: @MarcB mysqli requires that I rewrite my connection variable and for every query I need to add the connection using an assigned variable. I'll get to this probably this week but I just want basic functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be this:

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT temporary_password,temporary_username FROM $tbl_name");
```

Or you can make your like this:

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT temporary_password,temporary_username FROM $tbl_name where temporary_username = '".$_GET['temp_username']."'");
```

As you are not selecting the `temporary_username` from the Database so it is not checking the last condition in if condition.

That's it is working for OR condition and not for AND.

So use the above query and it will work for And condition also.

Comment: Thanks! I used your second statement as it compared my GET statement to the username in the database. Nice touch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
if($_GET[...snip...] && $_GET['temp_username'] != $row['temporary_username']){
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---this
```

Don't you think you might want to add it:

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT temporary_password FROM $tbl_name");
                                               ^----- here?
```

Comment: LOL its too early in the morning. Thats why I post on stackoverflow, to get a second pair of eyes on my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check username and password from database

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT temporary_password FROM $tbl_name where temp_username = $_GET['temp_username'] AND temporary_password = $_GET['temp_password'] ");
```

then if it both matched then grant it access else redirected to index.php
or it will be better to check `rowcount >0`

```
 if($_GET['temp_password'] == $row['temporary_password'] && $_GET['temp_username'] == $row['temporary_username']){
       // access granted
    }
else {
    //wrong credential
        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

**you should use pdo or mysqli since mysql_* is deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

You should add a WHERE statement into your query:

```
"SELECT count(*) from $tbl_name WHERE temporary_username = :username AND temporary_password = :password"
```